# formula to sum only cells with numbers and ignore cells with text

Tags: google-sheets

What formula would I use to sum a column of cells containing numbers and text to only sum the cells with numbers... example:

```
3
FALSE
FALSE
```

I want to only sum the cell with the number so the total would be 3

Answer (score 1):

`SUM()` ignores all non-numeric data:

```
=SUM( *your range here* )
```